# Trying to make/convert a simple temperature averaging function

Tags: python, syntax

So I've gotten to this part to decide which part to use as the further value away from the range of averages...

why am I getting syntax issues here????

```
if abs(S-K)>abs(S-K2):

    TempComp1=abs(S-K) 

else TempComp1=abs(S-K2)
```

So far I've been fairly well pleased with Python 3 over 2 it seems like it doesn't take hours to fix small snippets of code but at this point messing with different versions (or "letters") of loop types doesn't do anything, there's nothing about previous code that's changed besides putting in a TempComp1=0.0 earlier. It stops and puts the TempComp1 after the else in red. If it wasn't that and I mess with the parentheses within these statements then it just chooses to put something else nearby in red. I have already messed around with this for an hour I'm about to just delete this whole damn section and make two separate programs. Something is obviously not working here.

S and K, K2 are all floats. Besides trying to put this section in the whole program works.

Comment: You are missing a `:` in `else`,  `else:
    TempComp1=abs(S-K2)`

Comment: You need a colon `:` after the `else`

Comment: Pretty sure that's a syntax error in Python 2 as well.

Comment: If else statements aren't "loop types"

Comment: You could just do `temp = max(abs(S-K), abs(S-K2))`

Answer (score 2):

You missed a colon `:` after `else`.

```
if abs(S-K)>abs(S-K2):
    TempComp1=abs(S-K)
else: # colon here
    TempComp1=abs(S-K2)
```

Instead of all this, you can just write

```
TempComp1 = max(abs(S-K), abs(S-K2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a systex error, you are missing with the colon `:`, use the below code to get your result:-

```
if abs(S-K)>abs(S-K2):
    TempComp1=abs(S-K) 
else :    # This is where you are missing.
    TempComp1=abs(S-K2)
```

I hope now it will solve your problem.